# How to get git-log to display commits using relative revision syntax of git-parse-rev

Tags: git, git-log

git show-branch displays commits using the relative revision expressions that can be parsed by git-parse-rev, for example "dev~106^2~52".  How can I get the same output from git-log?

Comment: This question may be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128866/git-relative-revision-numbers

Answer (score 1):

No.

The documentation for `git log` (`git help log`) describes ways to customize the output using `--pretty=tformat:...`, but unfortunately there is no placeholder for `git describe`-style revision identifiers, nor is there a placeholder to run a shell command and use its output.  Either would make it possible to do what you want.  Perhaps you can suggest them to the Git developers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes?: Something like `git log | git name-rev --stdin`, that is, see the `git name-rev` man page for obtaining this format.

I had a similar question [describe a commit relative to a tag in parent^/ancestor~ format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16497511/717355) which was linked back here ;-)