# describe a commit relative to a tag in parent^/ancestor~ format

Tags: git

I'm looking to describe a particular commit relative to a more recent tag using the parent^ and ancestor generation~ format shown in specifying revisions section of git-rev-parse.

Is there a simple command for obtaining this format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628624/how-to-get-git-log-to-display-commits-using-relative-revision-syntax-of-git-pars?rq=1

Comment: Not really, see my answer

Answer (score 4):

After more googling found `git name-rev --tags --name-only <my-commit-ID>` did the trick. This is much better at indicating the commit is **in** the project than 'git describe` which can give false hope.

Found on [A few git tips you didn't know about, By Mislav Marohnic](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/07/git-tips/)

---

`git describe --contains <my-commit-ID>` also does the trick as described by [jszakmeister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/683080/jszakmeister)

Comment: What was the issue with `git describe --contains`?

Comment: The problem with `describe` is that you get a historical tag that is before your commit so you can easily think that your commit is within that tagged version when it really says that it definitely isn't in that tag! (i.e. it really ought to have a ^ not prefix), while the `name-rev` gives you a tag that does contain your commit in it's history. Plus you can use that  revision for walking the DAG (while describe is still really a pretty abbreviated sha1)

Comment: That's what `git describe` does by default, but `--contains` does what you want, and with one fewer option: "Instead of finding the tag that predates the commit, find the tag that comes after the commit, and thus contains it".  Trying both `name-rev --tags --name-only` and `describe --contains`, I get the same result.  Just thought you should know! :-)

Comment: @jszakmeister +1 for that. Just tested it and it worked for me as well ;-)

Comment: Also I had been trying `git tag --contains <my-commit-ID>`, which will tell you a tag, but not the parent^/ancestor~ values which I'd been looking for. Also, I'd found the `--tags` option in the `git describe` help page, and not read past it to see the following `--contains` option and that it implied `--tags`!